# Getting Text from Selected Index of multiple ListView Columns, C#

Tags: c#, listview

When a user selects an item, I would like to populate the fields from that selected item into textboxes. I am able to do this with the first column of data, but can't figure out how to get the next column:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            updateCustIdTextbox.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
            updateCustNameTextbox.Text = ???;
        }
    }
```

so I can get ID to link to its box, but how can i get Name to link to its box?

Comment: Look intot the `listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[i]` with i starting at 1. (0= is the main Item.)

Comment: superb. its a shame you did not write it as an answer to get the check mark thing.

Comment: too small to be a real answer..